# ember.js sideloaded models not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having to override a route to do some custom loading of models like this:

```
App.EventsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    origin = LJ.origin().join(',')
    location = [LJ.stripQuery(params.loc2), params.loc1].join(',')
    h = $.param(origin: origin, location: location)
    $.getJSON "#{LJ.CONFIG.api.url}/events?#{h}"
```

The JSON returned includes sideloaded models, but they aren't being loaded by ember. I'm guessing I need to do something to get them loaded but I don't know what. I'd appreciate any help on this.

[Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/mdi/5130107) of the returned JSON.

**Update**

Here's the model definition:

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend
  acts: DS.hasMany('App.Act')
  ageLimit: DS.attr('string')
  centsAdvance: DS.attr('number')
  centsDoor: DS.attr('number')
  currency: DS.attr('string')
  description: DS.attr('string')
  endsAt: DS.attr('number')
  priceAdvance: DS.attr('string')
  priceDoor: DS.attr('string')
  repeats: DS.attr('string')
  repeatsUntil: DS.attr('string')
  startsAt: DS.attr('number')
  title: DS.attr('string')
  url: DS.attr('string')
  venue: DS.belongsTo('App.Venue')
  venueSection: DS.attr('string')
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO this has nothing to do with your route but with your model. Make sure that you declare it like that (they have to be present of course)

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend({
  venue: DS.belongsTo('App.Venue'),
  acts: DS.hasMany('App.Act'),
  // go on with the model
});
```

I found it helpful to include a `{{ log event }}` into the template to dig into the controller and the model and make sure it really does not get loaded

P.s: You do return the ajax response in the route, do you not?

Comment: I do have that in my model definition. I've updated the question showing the definition. And yes, I am returning the Ajax response in the route.

Answer (score 0):

The link of the example JSON you are returning doesn't work, could you please provide a working sample?

You are going around Ember-data for your ajax call, which would mean you will need to handle deserializing it in a more manual manner.  If you want ember to do that for you, you need to call into the store, like:

```
App.EventsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        // other code here if necessary
        return this.store.find('event', params._id);
    }
```

Also, whenever I am not getting my related objects (venues in your case) loaded into the store, it is because the JSON isn't in the format Ember is expecting, which would look like this:

```
{
    Events: [{ Id: 1, Venues: [1], ... }], 
    Venues: [{ Id: 1, ... }]
}
```

NOT LIKE THIS:

```
{
    Events: [{ Id: 1, Venue: { Id: 1, ... }, ... }], 

}
```

Maybe this helps?